# Encryption of connection string done in server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3, database-connection

My application is connected to database through Encrypted connection string and Connection Key. I don't have any username or password. I could not find the code in my application code that encrypt my connection string using connection key. We used customized protection provider

My question is "Are these encryption happens in server level?" 
We are moving our DB to new server, how do i get new encryption strings.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? The SQL language has nothing to do with encryption.

Comment: We are using SQL server.

Comment: The encryption/decryption of the connection string occurs on the client (your app).

Comment: But I cannot find code that encrypt/decrypt connection string in my application code.